# In THREE.js how to change position of a point of chase camera?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Actually, I am new to THREE.js. I was trying to make a game in which I am using a spaceship as  a mesh, I created a chase camera for my model but I want to shift in position about which it is looking at. I am using following code :

```
var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,200,-500);

var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( spaceship1.matrixWorld );

camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
camera.lookAt(spaceship1.position);
```

I want to place my camera in front of spaceship  and it must look forward when I move, it should not look at spaceship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the camera as child of the spaceship.

```
camera.position.set( 0, 200, -500 );
spaceship1.add( camera );
```

Comment: hey can you please help me out. I am using particle system but I found there is no way of accessing each particles, so should I use .clone method to create clones instead of using particle system?

Comment: That seems unrelated. You should create a new question for that.